# "else if" statement within for loop within larger if/else if/else statement

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this in JavaScript?

```
if (name == 'foo') {
    exampleFunction('some_arg');
}
else if (name == 'bar') {
    exampleFunction('another_arg');
}
for (i in exampleObject) {
    else if (name == exampleObject[i].name) {
        exampleFunction(exampleObject[i].arg);
    }
}
else {
    exampleFunction('default')
}
```

I tried it, but got an "unexpected keyword else on line 8" (the "else if" within the for loop). Is there another way to do this?

edit: updated this to use exampleObject[i] in the loop. My bad!

Comment: Why do you even have a `for` loop if you never use your iterator, `i`?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

No.  I think the best way to accomplish this is to move the `for` loop into an `else` block and do the following

```
if (name == 'foo') {
    exampleFunction('some_arg');
}
else if (name == 'bar') {
    exampleFunction('another_arg');
}
else {
  var isFound = false;
  for (i in exampleObject) {
    if (name == exampleObject.name) {
      exampleFunction(exampleObject.arg);
      isFound = true;
    }
  }
  if (!isFound) {
    exampleFunction('default')
  }
}
```

Note: It looks like there are other errors in this code.  The `for` loop declares the `i` iteration variable but never actually uses it.  Did you mean for the `if` check in the `for` loop to use `i` instead of `name`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (name == 'foo') {
    exampleFunction('some_arg');
}
else if (name == 'bar') {
    exampleFunction('another_arg');
}
else {
  var isFound = false;
  for (i in exampleObject) {
    if (name == exampleObject.name) {
      exampleFunction(exampleObject.arg);
      isFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isFound) {
    exampleFunction('default')
  }
}
```

Here is the correct solution. It short circuts the if statements in the loop just like else if would short circuit. This is the same solution as #1 but it correctly short circuits.

Answer (score 0):

The following code looks wrong to me , have the for loop inside if block

```
for (i in exampleObject) {
    else if (name == exampleObject.name) {
        exampleFunction(exampleObject.arg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible. I would try an come up with a better example to show you how to do what you want, but honestly I am not sure what you want to do. The for loop is confusing me. Can you provide some more information?

Comment: This probably ought to be a comment.

Comment: I thought about that, but the first part of the question was can it be done, and my answer was it is not possible. The second part of his question was show a better example, that part I could not answer without some clarification and I didn't want to ask for clarification just to the second part of his question in a comment but answer the first part in an answer

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.  You are terminating the if-statement block with the last brace before the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, shouldn't this:

```
for (i in exampleObject) {
    else if (name == exampleObject.name) {
        exampleFunction(exampleObject.arg);
    }
}
```

be this:

```
for (i in exampleObject) {
    else if (name == i.name) {
        exampleFunction(i.arg);
    }
}
```

Though i don't know much (if anything) about js, this is just a guess at something that isn't even the problem you're talking about.

Would you be adverse to doing it like this:

```
bit = 0;
if (name == 'foo') {
    exampleFunction('some_arg');
}
else if (name == 'bar') {
    exampleFunction('another_arg');
}
else {
    bit = 1;
}

bit2 = 0;
while(bit == 1){
    for (i in exampleObject) {
        if (name == i.name) {
            exampleFunction(i.arg);
            bit = 0
            bit2 = 1;
        }
    }
}

if(bit2 = 0){
    exampleFunction('default');
}
```

?

Comment: Javascript has `break`.  No need to set a flag to stop the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help?

```
found = false

if (name == 'foo') {
    found = true 
    exampleFunction('some_arg');
}
else if (name == 'bar') {
    found = true
    exampleFunction('another_arg');
}
else {
  for (i in exampleObject) {
    if (name == i.name) {
        exampleFunction(i.arg);
        found = true
        break;
    }
  }
}

if !found:
   exampleFunction('default')
```